# Passing vector to function (pointers/addresses)

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

In the following situation, how does the parameter-list for `sortMyVectors` have to look like, and how do I call it from within `myFunction` ?

```
std::vector<Vector2> myFunction ( MyObj * myObj ) {

    std::vector<Vector2> myVectors;
    // fill with lots of Vector2(double x, double y) objects

    sortMyVectors( ???-myVectors, ???-myObj);

    return myVectors;
} 


void sortMyVectors( vector<Vector2> &myVectors, const MyObj &myObj) {

    // sort the std::vector using myObj
    // modifies order of Vector2s within the passed-in myVectors
    // does not modify myObj
    // need to be able to access with myVectors[0].x here...
}
```

The way this is called is `myFunction(&(*myObj));`, where `myObj` is a `list<MyObj>::iterator`. Is there a cleaner way to write this?

Comment: It's nothing special: `sortMyVectors(myVectors, *myObj);` `myVectors` is a variable, so you can pass it to a reference directly; `myObj` is a pointer, so you need to dereference it once to be compatible with `MyObj&`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation. However, I get this error: "undefined reference to `sortMyVectors(std::vector<_Vector2, std::allocator<_Vector2> >&, MyObj&)`"

Comment: You can move `sortMyVectors` ahead of `myFunction` in the file, or add a forward declaration for it at the top of .c or in the .h file: `void sortMyVectors( vector<Vector2> &myVectors, const MyObj &myObj);`

Comment: Oh... yeah that's the problem (I had it in a class and forgot to type `Classname::myFunction(...)`. Great, that works now :) Could you also have a look at the way I call `myFunction` (bottom of my question) and let me know how I can make the `&(*)` a little cleaner?

Comment: You can change to `myFunction(list<MyObj>::const_iterator& myObj)`, and leave everything else as-is: it should compile and run, and you'd be able to pass your iterator directly.

Comment: I've changed it to `myFunction( const MyObj & myObj)` and call it using `myFunction(*myObj)`. That looks a lot nicer. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sortMyVectors( ???-myVectors, ???-myObj);
```

Answer:

```
sortMyVectors(myVectors, *myObj);
```

As it seems you are having some basic trouble with pointers at the moment (and I suspect this is practice for some kind of homework), it would probably be a bit too advanced to suggest you learn iterators, but you should look into that later along with `std::sort` which would be quite hard to beat with any handrolled sort.

As an attempt to improve your understanding of pointers:

```
MyObj* myObjPtr = ...;
```

This is a pointer. It points to a memory address. Assuming it points to a valid one, we can do this:

```
MyObj& myObjRef = *myObjPtr;
```

Now we dereferenced the pointer to get the pointee, and assigned it to a reference which is also like a pointer but hides the pointer/pointee distinction (not requiring operator* to access the pointee/referenced object).

In response to a comment you made:

> The "sorting" basically sorts these vectors by their distance from
>   another vector, but only in a particular case, so I don't know if
>   there is a standard way of doing that..

std::sort accepts a strict weak ordering predicate (basically a function or function object which returns true/false based on whether element1 < element2). Example:

```
bool length_is_less(const string& str1, const string& str2)
{
    return str1.size() < str2.size();
}

vector<string> my_strings = ...;
sort(my_strings.begin(), my_strings.end(), length_is_less);
```

The above code sorts strings based on their length from shortest string to longest string, rather than the default behavior (default operator< implementation for strings) of sorting them by string order (alphabetical order, crudely speaking).

Given this ability to define your own predicate for comparing objects, you can basically sort anything by any condition using `std::sort`.

Comment: Thx for the explanation, quick question, if a constructor has a paramater `const MyObj &myObj`, how can I then assign this to a data member `MyObj * myObj` (sort of the inverse of what you explained in the above)? Or should I also change the data member?

Comment: @Ben Simplified answer: you can't since your const reference is read-only and MyObj* is mutable. That would violate the whole point of const safety to keep you from modifying things accidentally that you don't want. If it was const MyObj*, then you can do: const MyObj* myObjPtr = &myObjRef;

Comment: @Ben Crudely speaking, it's operator& to get from a pointee to a pointer, and operator* to get from a pointer to pointee.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent sorting, use `std::sort` which allows you to pass in a predicate object such as `MyObj`, as long as it has an `operator()` to do the sorting. It uses iterators rather than containers which gives more flexibility.

Comment: The "sorting" basically sorts these vectors by their distance from another vector, but only in a particular case, so I don't know if there is a standard way of doing that... However, my question was what I need to put for the pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want myFunction to call sortMyVectors passing in myObj and myVectors, do the following:

```
    std::vector<Vector2> myFunction ( MyObj * myObj ) { 

        std::vector<Vector2> myVectors; 
        // fill with lots of Vector2(double x, double y) objects 

        sortMyVectors(myVectors, myObj); 

        return myVectors; 
    }  


    void sortMyVectors(vector<Vector2> &myVectors, const MyObj *myObj) { 

        // Check for null pointer of myObj
        // sort the std::vector using myObj 
        // need to be able to access with myVectors[0].x here... 
    }
```

Comment: Well, I'm using the reference now, such that I don't need to do the null pointer check ;)